# Double differential equals zero?

Tags: calculus, differential-geometry, differential-forms, exterior-algebra

In *Elementary Differential Geometry 2nd ed, Barret O'niell,* Section 1.6

O'niell states that since p-forms follow the alternation rule, then a repeated differential is necessarily zero, that is

$$dx \wedge dx = 0$$

Yet, differentiating position with respect to time, we get

$$a = \frac {d^2 p} {dt^2}$$

then integrating back to position

$$p = \int_0^t \int_0^t a\,dt\,dt $$

which clearly does not equal zero, yet in my tangled brain looks something like $dt\,dt$. Why is this not zero?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proper way of writing a second antiderivative in terms of a double integral is
$$
p(t) = \int_0^t\!\!\int_0^{t_1} a(t_2)\, dt_2\,dt_1
$$
This can be seen from two applications of the fundamental theorem of calculus. We see that the two differentials are indeed of different variables.

Comment: Thankyou! that makes sense

Comment: In that case is the expression $\frac{d^2 p}{dt^2}$ an abuse of notation since the dt in each derivative from p to a are different?

Answer (score 1):

The notation $da \land db$ indicate a [differential $2-$ form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_form), that is a different thing than a  ''double differential'' (whatever this means).

Intuitively  you can think at $da \land db$ as the ''infinitesimal'' oriented area of a parallelogram that has sides the two ''vectors''  $da$ and $db$. So if the two vectors are parallel, as in the case $da=db=dx$, this area is zero.